# Creating dynamic query which has also has a sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use two queries in SQL Server, which I would like to combine and create a single query. Tried few options but of not much success.

Query 1

```
select emp_id, name, age 
from employee 
where age > 50
```

Query 2

```
select dept_id, dept_name 
from department 
where emp_id = 'COMPANY.ID' + emp_id
```

The issue in combining the two queries is, though query 1 can return multiple rows, I can't use a subquery to directly use `emp_id` from query 1 in query 2 since the `emp_id` in query 2 has a prefix of 'COMPANY.ID.'+emp_id. Any suggestions?

`COMPANY.ID` is a constant that gets prefixed to `emp_id` before saving it in  department table.

Example employee table

```
emp_id      name       age
-----------------------------
123         John       45
345         Susan      34
789         Pat        66
```

Example department table

```
emp_id                     dept_id                      dept_name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
COMPANY.ID.123             123                           Accounting
COMPANY.ID.345             123                           Accounting
```

Hope these examples help understand my dataset

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help your explanation.

Comment: I am having hard time figuring out how condition `where emp_id = 'COMPANY.ID'+emp_id` will ever be fulfilled...

Comment: Where `'COMPANY.ID.'` came from ? Is a constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you are trying to pull out the departments that have at least one employee older than 50.

One solution would be to use an `EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT dept_id, dept_name
FROM department d
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM employee e
    WHERE 
        CONCAT('COMPANY.ID.', e.emp_id) = d.emp_id
        AND e.age > 50
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b9cc5d29ef03ffe0fe06815b9fd65e2f)**

Comment: Thanks GMB, Aakanksha and others for their time. This works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want as 
Query 2 is totally wrong and would never match instead would have used like `%CompanyId%`

```
    select distinct dept_id, dept_name 
   from 
    department where empid IN (
    select emp_id from 
   employee where age > 50 and empid 
  like '%CompanyId%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two tables using join

```
SELECT d.dept_id, d.dept_name
FROM department d
INNER JOIN employee e
ON CONCAT('COMPANY.ID.', e.emp_id) = d.emp_id
WHERE e.age > 50
```